# Rom building repo sync errors, file not found, cannot fetch

Tags: android, terminal, custom-rom

[These are the errors I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUOrx.png)
[This is the code that I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD51x.png)

I was setting up my Linux computer for building "afterlife" custom ROM, from android manifest, guide link is here - https://github.com/AfterLifePrjkt13/android_manifest

I am new to this Linux and this custom ROM stuff, so i don't no any fix, and didn't try anything..